# Typescript global variables

Tags: typescript

Is there a convenient way to have global variables accessible within modules,without compiler errors, ie CANVAS_WIDTH used below?

```
    export class Bullet {


        x: number = 22;
        y: number = 22;

        constructor (speed: number) {
            this.xVelocity = speed;
        }

        inBounds() {
            return this.x >= 0 && this.x <= CANVAS_WIDTH &&
                this.y >= 0 && this.y <= CANVAS_HEIGHT;
        };
}
}
```

Comment: where you will set the value for CANVAS_WIDTH?

Comment: in the game class  which imports the module with the  Bullet class GameObjects = module("GameObjects")

Comment: You have CANVAS_WIDTH in Game class and need to access it in Bullet class. Am i right?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to define those properties as static, then you can access it easily like this,

```
export class Game {
    static canvas: JQuery;
    static CANVAS_WIDTH: number;
    static CANVAS_HEIGHT: number;
    bullet: Bullet;

    constructor(canvasElem: JQuery) {
        Game.canvas = canvasElem;
        Game.CANVAS_WIDTH = Game.canvas.width();
        Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT = Game.canvas.height();
    }
}

export class Bullet {
    x: number = 22;
    y: number = 22;

    public inBounds() {
        // accessing static properties
        return this.x >= 0 && this.x <= Game.CANVAS_WIDTH && this.y >= 0 && this.y <= Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

---

This compiles to:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var Game = (function () {
        function Game(canvasElem) {
            Game.canvas = canvasElem;
            Game.CANVAS_WIDTH = Game.canvas.width();
            Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT = Game.canvas.height();
        }
        return Game;
    })();
    exports.Game = Game;

    var Bullet = (function () {
        function Bullet() {
            this.x = 22;
            this.y = 22;
        }
        Bullet.prototype.inBounds = function () {
            // accessing static properties
            return this.x >= 0 && this.x <= Game.CANVAS_WIDTH && this.y >= 0 && this.y <= Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT;
        };
        return Bullet;
    })();
    exports.Bullet = Bullet;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=dhdh.js.map
```

Comment: added the compiled JS file

Answer (score 3):

This is a contrived example, but rather than trying to push to global scope, you can use the module scope to enclose a variable that will be used from several classes.

```
module MyModule {
    var x: number = 5;

    export class FirstClass {
        doSomething() {
            x = 10;
        }
    }

    export class SecondClass {
        showSomething() {
            alert(x.toString());
        }
    }
}

var a = new MyModule.FirstClass();
a.doSomething();

var b = new MyModule.SecondClass();
b.showSomething();
```

All the usual rules about multiple things using the same variable apply here - you don't want to enforce a particular order of events on the calling code.

---

Compiles to:

```
var MyModule;
(function (MyModule) {
    var x = 5;

    var FirstClass = (function () {
        function FirstClass() {
        }
        FirstClass.prototype.doSomething = function () {
            x = 10;
        };
        return FirstClass;
    })();
    MyModule.FirstClass = FirstClass;

    var SecondClass = (function () {
        function SecondClass() {
        }
        SecondClass.prototype.showSomething = function () {
            alert(x.toString());
        };
        return SecondClass;
    })();
    MyModule.SecondClass = SecondClass;
})(MyModule || (MyModule = {}));

var a = new MyModule.FirstClass();
a.doSomething();

var b = new MyModule.SecondClass();
b.showSomething();
```

Comment: Does this still work in the latest version of typescript? It does not appear the example compiles...

Comment: added compiled js for comparison

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I want to *encourage* this, but to answer the OP's question literally:

#### You can put anything you want into global scope and then refer to it elsewhere.

For instance, you could put the following on your index.html equivalent:

```
function logit(x, loc) {
  if (console && console.log) {
    console.log(loc, JSON.stringify(x, null, '  '));
  }
}
```

Now you can use this anywhere you want in one of at least two ways.

#### Kludge your global scope.

`(window as any).logit(item, "some location")`

Ewwww.

#### Use declare

You can also refer to it using [`declare`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40700848/1028230).

So in a regular TypeScript file:

```
declare const logit: (x: any, loc: string) => void;
// you could also just use
// declare const logit: any;

export default class MyClass {
  public handleIt(x: string) {
    logit(x, "MyClass.handleIt");
    // ... logic
  }
}
```

Note that any file, not just "index.html", is fair game as a launching point to push stuff into the global scope. Just remember that you could get into trouble if you were, say, lazy loading a module.

---

#### Your example

So for you, set those two values globally however you want (or maybe a non-TypeScript library does it for you, which would *almost* make this a valid use case), and then do something like...

```
declare let CANVAS_WIDTH: number; // maybe const, I don't know your use case.
declare let CANVAS_HEIGHT: number;

export class Bullet {
  x: number = 22;
  y: number = 22;

  constructor (speed: number) {
    this.xVelocity = speed;
  }

  inBounds() {
    return this.x >= 0 && this.x <= CANVAS_WIDTH &&
    this.y >= 0 && this.y <= CANVAS_HEIGHT;
  };
}
```

But, again, this is *highly* anti-pattern, and probably indicates a code smell. You want to have static values on another class [as Rajagopal 웃 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13822619/1028230).