# Why is `declare` word used in the `d.ts` files

Tags: typescript

Whenever `tsc` generates `d.ts` files, it includes `declare` word there, like this:

```
export declare class Moment {
    name: string;
}
```

Now, `declare` in `ts` files is used to say to `tsc` that no `js` should be generated for the type with `declare`. So it makes sense in the `ts` files. However, no `js` is generated from `d.ts` files anyway, why use the word there?

I tried to remove `declare` word from the above code:

```
export class Moment {
    name: string;
}
```

and it worked the same.

I've found the following [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html):

> If a file has the extension .d.ts then each root level definition must
>   have the declare keyword prefixed to it. This helps make it clear to
>   the author that there will be no code emitted by TypeScript. The
>   author needs to ensure that the declared item will exist at runtime.

So is it the only purpose of the `declare` in `d.ts` files?

Plese note, this is not the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019987/what-does-declare-do-in-export-declare-class-actions), as my question is about using `declare` in `d.ts` files, not `ts` files.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple.

when you want to export a declaration of variable or function you have two ways to do that:

1. you can create a variable or a function in one line and after that you can export it in a new line.

   To do that you need first "declare" the variable or the function, after that you can export it.

   for example:

```js
declare class Moment {
    name: string;
}

export Moment;
```

2. you can export it in one line without declaring it first.
   for example:

```js
export class Moment {
    name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ".d.ts" files and ".ts" are processed by the same transpiler. And keywoard meaning are the same. According to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) and the [article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/):

> The declare keyword is used for ambient declarations where you want to
>   define a variable that may not have originated from a TypeScript file.

The `declare` keyword makes transpiler does not produce any real JavaScript code and allows to use "declared" object in other TypeScript files.

Comment: This does not make sense, because `.d.ts` files *never* produce any JS code -- it's a "typings" file and is only used to inform the compiler about the shape of types.  `.d.ts` cannot contain implementations, so `declare` is redundant there.