# Typescript declaration file - difference between "export declare" and "export"

Tags: typescript

I'm learning Typescript. As I study some source files, I find that sometimes there is `export declare ...` and sometimes there is just `export ...` in the declaration file `.d.ts`.

After some tests, it seems to me they are equivalent. Without `declare` there is no difference.

I know `declare` is needed without `export`. For example, `declare var test:any;`.

But is it true that `export declare` and `export` are equivalent?

Side question: is it true that `declare` isn't needed at all for `interface` and `type`? In the `.d.ts` file if I put just `interface test{}`, then `test` is available everywhere without `declare`. Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'declare' do in 'export declare class Actions'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019987/what-does-declare-do-in-export-declare-class-actions)

Answer (score 0):

the `declare` flag tells TypeScript that the shape of the class or interface is being defined somewhere else, not *here*;  e.g., could be used for classes/interfaces/functions being served by a CDN and imported by a `<script>` tag in the index.html file (among other things, of course).

If you're *creating* a class or interface for use in your application, you shouldn't need the `declare` flag.

Example:

```js
// my-cool-object.ts

export interface MyCoolObject {
// stuff in my object
}
```

```js
// my-cool-project.ts

import { MyCoolObject } from './my-cool-object';  // or wherever the interface definition file is located;

const myObject: MyCoolObject;

// ...more code goes here
```