# How do I include a JavaScript script file in Angular and call a function from that script?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a JavaScript file called `abc.js` that has a 'public' function called `xyz()`. I want to call that function in my Angular project. How do I do that?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Refer the scripts inside the `angular-cli.json` (`angular.json` when using angular 6+) file.

```
"scripts": [
    "../path" 
 ];
```

then add in `typings.d.ts` (create this file in `src` if it does not already exist)

```
declare var variableName:any;
```

Import it in your file as

```
import * as variable from 'variableName';
```

Comment: i added path in scripts as 
"scripts": [
    "./assets/common_header_sidebar.js" 
 ];
then in typing.d.ts 
i wrote declare var commonHeader:any;
and then in my ts file i wrote 
import * as commonHeaderModule from 'commonHeader';
but getting "Cannot find module 'commonHeader'." error

Comment: `commonHeader` must be the name of the object exported in the javascript file

Comment: yes commonHeader is the function name that i have to export from the js file

Comment: i might sound silly for asking this. but how the file name in the path(declared in angular-cli.json) and declaring name of the object in typing.d.ts file is related. 
since i am importing from the name of the declared object not the file

Comment: can you create a `plunker` to reproduce

Comment: will uploading the js file do the job ??
since i haven't created any plunker till now . so might take time in that

Comment: done with the integration it is just that i had to declare the function in my ts file where i was using it and import was not required. Thanks a ton .

Comment: Can I use online link in the script tag? Is there any way to use online **JS** file link to use in application?

Comment: you can use the script reference too

Comment: @Ameya I didn''t understand your question

Comment: We don't have to import once again if we declare the variable in typing.d.ts

Comment: I could see plugin name in chrome console, but unable to import  in ts file.

Comment: I don't have 'typings.d.ts' file in my project, so what should I do?

Comment: @Aravind what if I don't have typing.d.ts file in my Angular 4 project?

Comment: @HabibM.Farooq can you please share me your code and the steps you tried or try creating a new post if it is completely different from this post

Comment: @Aravind well I was trying to add a js file and when I search for a typing.d.ts file I didn't find any. 
I create my project from Angular CLI "ng new appname" by this method. 
And everything is working fine but there is no typings.d.ts file in my project. 
Do I have to create it by myself or is it some problem or some error?

Comment: @ HabibM.Farooq you must create this file

Comment: FYI angular-cli.json has been renamed to angular.json from angular 6+

Comment: Add a `typings.d.ts` file in your `src` folder if it does not already exist.

Comment: Still has an error when trying to import it : "Cannot find module 'myVariableName' or its corresponding type declarations."

Comment: How can this work? Doesn't work for me,.. How is your import linked to the script?

Answer (score 53):

Add external js file in **index.html**.

```
<script src="./assets/vendors/myjs.js"></script>
```

Here's **myjs.js** file :

```
var myExtObject = (function() {

    return {
      func1: function() {
        alert('function 1 called');
      },
      func2: function() {
        alert('function 2 called');
      }
    }

})(myExtObject||{})


var webGlObject = (function() { 
    return { 
      init: function() { 
        alert('webGlObject initialized');
      } 
    } 
})(webGlObject||{})
```

Then declare it is in component like below

**demo.component.ts**

```
declare var myExtObject: any;
declare var webGlObject: any;

constructor(){
    webGlObject.init();
}

callFunction1() {
    myExtObject.func1();
}

callFunction2() {
    myExtObject.func2();
}
```

**demo.component.html**

```html
<div>
    <p>click below buttons for function call</p>
    <button (click)="callFunction1()">Call Function 1</button>
    <button (click)="callFunction2()">Call Function 2</button>
</div>
```

It's working for me...

Comment: Very thorough example thanks, it worked for me on angular 6. None of the other answers worked.

Comment: Fwiw, [here are some explanations of what `declare` does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35019987/1028230) -- essentially "_`declare` is used to tell TypeScript that the variable has been created elsewhere_" (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020317/1028230)).

Comment: I think the index.html file is empty by design and I think you should keep it that way. The ng serve should take care of all javascript files.

Answer (score 49):

In order to include a global library, eg `jquery.js` file in the scripts array from `angular-cli.json` (`angular.json` when using angular 6+):

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

After this, restart ng serve if it is already started.

Comment: how do you import on the typescript file?

Comment: to import in ts file use - `declare var $: any;`

Comment: angular-cli.json file has been renamed/replaced with angular.json in version 6+ of Angular.

Comment: Either this isn't working in 2021 or there is a step missing

Comment: What else after adding the file to array?  @alansiqueira27 good point

Answer (score 22):

You can either

```
import * as abc from './abc';
abc.xyz();
```

or

```
import { xyz } from './abc';
xyz()
```

Comment: what am i supposed to do when the file is hosted somewhere but not in the local repo?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Getting errors in both methods. 
Well I have a .js file in my project but when I import by first method its give me error in compiling and can't find any module when I use the second method. 
And I am just using slick slider.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this issue by adding `"allowJs": true` within "compilerOptions" in *tsconfig.json* file!

Answer (score 4):

**- Let us assume our script file `custom.js` looks like this: -**

```
var utilObj = {
    dummyFunc: () => {
        console.log('Calling dummy function!');
    }
}
```

**- Add your javascript/script file in scripts array in `angular.json` file.**

```
"scripts": [
    "src/custom.js" 
 ],
```

Should look like this: -

[image]

**- Add below code snippet in `typings.d.ts`. If this file doesn't exist, create one in `src` folder.**

```
declare var utilObj:any;
```

Keep your variable name similar to property of script file. Here `utilObj` is the property name.

**- Now, You can consume this script/js file directly in your component or .ts file.**

You need not import the file in component file or .ts file now as we have given the typing defination for the script file already in `typings.d.ts` file.

Example: -

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('Starting Application!');
  utilObj.dummyFunc();
}
```

**- Output: -**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was facing similar issue and resolved it by adding my `js` file to `scripts` inside `options` in `angular.json` file.

And declaring the object I created in JavaScript file in `typings.d.ts` file.

Here's link that might help you a bit more on this:- https://medium.com/@darediP/communication-between-js-and-ts-files-with-angular-and-electron-6f93cecd179e

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but if you feel that you are properly exporting your JavaScript helper function utils/javaScriptHelperFunction.js

```
export function javaScriptFunction() {
   // DO HELPER FUNCTION STUFF
}
```

If you have done your checks as mentioned in the above answers, just **close** and **open** your code editor...start with the quick basic troubleshooting before going down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with including Muuri in my Angular project.
I solved it like below:
Solution 1:
Use the cdn of that script in index.html
place those cdns in the head of index.html not at
the end of body tag

Solution 2:
download those script files and place them in assets folder inside
app folder and add script tags in the head of index.html
not at the end of body tag.

Solution 3:(Muuri Case Study)
first of all install murri(or your intended library) using > npm i muuri     then import typings file from murri package in the component
import Muuri from '.../node_modules/muuri/src/index';
then use it in ngOnInit method like this:
const muuri_grid01 = new Muuri('.muuri-grid-01');

Answer (score 0):

Add folder js.
[image]

```js
 **JS**

function changeLoading() 
{
    $('body').append(
      '<div id="overlay">' +
      '<img id="loading" src="assets/loading.png">'+
      '</div>'
  );
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#overlay').remove();
    window.open( link );
  }, 1000); //2 seconds

}
```

```css
 **CSS**

  #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
#loading {
    width: 50px;
    height: 57px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -28px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

```html
 **HTML**

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeLoading();" type="button"></button>
```

}

**angular.json**
[image]

**Component**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private appService: AppService,
                private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
                private router: Router,
                @Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document) {           };
    
     private addScript(scriptSrc: string) {
                  const script = this.document.createElement('script');
                  script.type = 'text/javascript';
                  script.src = scriptSrc;
                  script.async = true;
                  this.document.head.appendChild(script);
              }
    
    ipAddress:string = '';

    ngOnInit()  
    {  
      this.addScript('js/javascript.js');  
    }   
   

  }
```