# How to use methods from external js in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular6

I need to call a function from external js file into my Angular component

I already go through the related question

- [How can i import external js file in Angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349460/how-can-i-import-external-js-file-in-angular-5)
- [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My External JS (external.js)

```
var radius = 25;

function calculateRadius(pi) {
    let piValue = 3.14159;

    if(pi) {
        piValue = pi;
    }

    var result = piValue * radius * radius;
    console.log('Result: ', result);
}

function wrapperMethod(pi) {
    console.log('Hi, this is from wrapper method');
    calculateRadius(pi)
}
```

I added the said JS file in the angular.json under scripts block

```
"scripts": [
    "src/assets/external.js",
]
```

In the CircleComponent, I would like to call the method

```
import wrapperMethod from '../../src/assets/external.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-circle',
  templateUrl: './circle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./circle.component.css']
})
export class CircleComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        wrapperMethod(3.14159);
    }
}
```

But its failing to call the method. Kindly assist me how to achieve this.

Note: The said methods as just an example methods, I want to implement this logic with the complex code file. The said question tells about typings.d.ts, but I don't know where is typings.d.ts in my Angular project. Kindly brief me regarding this. If the said question gives good solution means, why should I post this question.

Angular Structure (Created using Angular CLI)

[image]

I don't know where is `typings.d.ts`, could anyone please tell me where is typings.d.ts - which is mentioned in the said questions [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44817349/1417185)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j)

Comment: @Paritosh could you please tell me where is typings.d.ts

Comment: if you have created your project using angular-cli, then it will be there under `src` folder

Comment: @Paritosh I attached the snapshot of my Angular project structure for you reference. Kindly assist me.

Comment: @Paritosh are you there, could you please assist or just remove the duplicate tag in my question.

Comment: check my asnwer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52420112/1417185

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this below steps

```
1) First add a reference of your external JS file for importing it to the component. 
   import * as wrapperMethods from '../../src/assets/external.js';

2) Now declare a "var" of the same name that your function has inside external JS.
   declare var wrapperMethods: any;

3) ngOninit(){
    wrapperMethods();
   }
```

Comment: I added the `var wrapperMethod: any;` statement just after the import statement. I'm getting the following errors `SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module` and `ERROR TypeError: "Object(...) is not a function"`

Comment: have you added this 'declare var wrapperMethods: any;' above the angular Decorator code?

Comment: YES... Just after the `import` statement and just above the `@Component()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

put your external .js file under scripts in build

[image: like that]

if still can not see methods inside it put in in index.html

```
<script src="assets/PATH_TO_YOUR_JS_FILE"></script>
```

in your component after import section

```
declare var FUNCTION_NAME: any;

ANY_FUNCTION() {
    FUNCTION_NAME(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused with `typings.d.ts`. Follow below steps.

1.Add your external file inside `assets` folder. The content of this file will be by default included as per your `angular-cli.json`.

2.The function of your js which you're going to use must be `exported`. i.e.

```
export function hello() {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

3.Import your file inside your component as below.

```
 import * as ext from '../assets/some-external.js';
```

4.Now you can reference it like

```
ext.hello();
```

Comment: I can't change a single code in the external js, I'm having only privilege to write whatever in my file, I can consume the external file but I can't change the content. i.e., I can't add the `export` keyword in front of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Steps:-
1. create a external js file. 
2. In component.ts use the below code.

ngOnInit() {  
  this.loadJsFile(JsFilePath);  
}  
public loadJsFile(url) {  
  let node = document.createElement('script');  
  node.src = url;  
  node.type = 'text/javascript';  
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);  
} 

3. If u use jquery then define selector in html to render. Or store data in variable.
```

4. Make sure you have to add jquery cdn in index.html and you have to install Jquery and its types package from npm.