# Use common Javascript file in Angular and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a javascript file named `sum.js`

```
var addNumber = function (a,b){
  return a + b;
}
exports.addNumber = addNumber;
```

I want to use same `sum.js` file's `addNumber` function in `nodeJS` and in `Angular 5`. How can I do it. Is there any ways to do it?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Something like a shared library ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun yeah right it should work in angular and javascript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418149/how-to-use-methods-from-external-js-in-angular/52418929#52418929

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya will same code work in `NodeJS` also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to use it in `NodeJS` as

```
var sum = require('./sum.js');
```

But I was not able to use it in `Angular`, So I declared `var require: any;` on the top.

```
 declare var require: any;
 var sum = require('./sum.js');
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010219/6555572) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an npm package and use it in both:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-a-beautiful-tiny-npm-package-and-publish-it-2881d4307f78

Comment: During development it will be so tedious to build it and then use it in angular and node.. And not 100% if it'll at both end ie Node and angular..

Answer (score 0):

You can give the reference of your js file in angular-cli.json like below

```
"scripts": [
    ....
    "./assets/js/sum.js"
],
```

and then in your .ts of angular you can directly use it by declaring it like

```
import * as sum from '../../........./sum.js' //ref of ur file

class xyz {
   let a = 0,b=1
   constructor() { sum.addNumber(a, b); }
}
```

Comment: I have thousands of functions in `.js` file so each time I'll have to do this. Or I can access it using *?

Comment: Also if each of your js file returns an object, then you can directly have that as " declare var objectName : any