# Use a pure JS library in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use jsdom in this Angular 5 project.

```
npm install jsdom --save
```

Now, I import the library:

```
import * as jsdom from "jsdom";
```

And then use the library in my code just like the [npm readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) suggests:

```
const inMemoryDom = new jsdom('<html>...</html>');
```

The app crashes and console reads `Cannot find module "child_process"`. Any clue what this could mean?

Comment: have you defined `jsdom` in angular-cli.json file?

Comment: no, I don't know how to do that. Any link you can suggest that demonstrates this process?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j/44817445

Comment: Thanks Kumar, learned something new :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jsdom` library is meant to be used with nodejs, it's therefore not possible to use it inside a browser environment. Because modules like `child_process` are only available inside a nodejs environment.

In theory the only option to run it inside a browser environment would be to use something like `browserify`.

Inside the github repository of `jsdom` there's a [**section**](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#running-jsdom-inside-a-web-browser) explaining what has to be done to use it inside a browser environment.

Comment: What would be the point of using jsom in an browser environment in the first place? I don't really see the point to be honest.

Comment: @PatrickKelleter it's an app that load the HTML contents of legacy websites on a dead intranet, parses the contents and uploads bits to a database. It's not pretty but it's effective :-)

Comment: At want prevents you from doing this using nodejs ? A nodejs server could also request the contents and parse it.

Comment: @Cyrix, thanks that makes sense now. Will try browserify, or will stick to const parser = new DOMParser(); Indeed, nodejs could be an option in this case. I wanted to skip writing a backend as Angular seems a good fit for adding buttons etc. to help the engine make decisions when parsing.