# Getting error while calling the method from external file using Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting the following error while calling the method name from external file using Angular4.

Error:

```
ERROR in src/app/about/about.component.ts(22,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'checkJS'.
```

I am providing my code below.

**about.componet.html:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a routerLink ='/'>Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a [routerLink] = "['/about', 'http://example.com/jslib/jslib.js']" routerLinkActive="active">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here I am passing the external file path in URL.

**about.componet.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit,AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  aboutData = [];
  filePath:string;
  constructor(private router:Router,private route:ActivatedRoute,private http:Http) { }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    $('#title').attr('style','font-weight:bold');
    $.getScript(this.filePath,function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        checkJS();
      }, 5000);
    })
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
        this.filePath = params['filepath'];
    });
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/articles').subscribe(
      (res:Response)=>{
        this.aboutData = res.json();
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my external .js file code.

```
var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

window.onload = function () {
    if (typeof (jQuery) != "undefined") {
        checkJS();
    }
}
function checkJS(){
 $('#title').html('LOADED CONTENT FROM REMOTE FILE');
}
```

I am calling that function (`i.e-checkJS`) from that external .js file which is given above but getting error while code is compiling.

Comment: Have you included this script in your `angular-cli.json`?

Comment: I posted all the typescript code. Please check it.

Comment: You really still need to add this external file declaration in the `angular-cli.json` file then import it manually. This is how I link jQuery whenever I needed it. You can also refer to this answer (similar question) https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817445/7950729

Comment: Try to access the checkJS() from the browser console. If it's accessible then try to declare it like declare let checkJS: any.

Comment: @NiralMunjariya : I did not get your point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the function manually outside of the class so that TypeScript knows that it exists:

```
declare function checkJS();
```

Your File should look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit,AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
declare function checkJS();
@Component({
    selector: 'app-about',
    templateUrl: './about.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    aboutData = [];
    filePath:string;
    constructor(private router:Router,private 
        route:ActivatedRoute,private http:Http) { }
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        $('#title').attr('style','font-weight:bold');
        $.getScript(this.filePath,function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                checkJS();
            }, 5000);
        })
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
        this.filePath = params['filepath'];
    });
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/articles').subscribe(
        (res:Response)=>{
            this.aboutData = res.json();
        }
      )
    }
}
```

Take a look at line 8.

Comment: In `declare` again showing error. `i.e- Modifier can not be appear here .`

Comment: You have to declare the function outside of the Component Class, e.g. at the end of the file

Comment: Actually I did not get it where I will do the change.