# How to manage js files in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am developing a MEAN app and my folder structure is as follows:

[image]

I have added a js file under /angular/src/assets/js for some jQuery things.

For that I have installed jQuery using npm.

Now I need to call that js file through **angular.cli.json** file.

**angular.cli.json:**

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "angular/src",
  "outDir": "angular/dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "../src/assets/js/custom.js"
  ],
```

Since I am pointing the root to "angular/src", there is a problem of including the jquery.min.js in the scripts part which is located under "mean/node_modules/" and ends in "not found" error.

angular.cli.json file looking for "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" inside the "angular/src" root path.

Is there any way to solve this without changing my folder structure?

Need someone's valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be linking js files directly in index.html.

If you want it to be compiled and maintained by angular, check this link

[How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/

Comment: I have followed the same . I have installed jquery using npm. I have included it in the scripts in angular.cli.json file. Also I have added "import * as $ from 'jquery';" in my component.ts file. But still am getting, "$ is not defined" error.

Comment: You might have missed adding the typings. JQuery will not have typings by default. So angular compiler will not know what to do with those files. Refer this link https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Remove the scripts link from the angular.cli.json then include it in your index html with script tag.

It works fine.