# How to import external js file in angular5 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, import, angular5

I've just joined an angular 5 project (new to the tech).
I need to use functions from an external javascript file.

I found some information here : [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j)

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

1. I added my js file in the project and declared it in the **.angular-cli.json** :
   `"scripts": [
       "./assets/js/kia.js"
     ],`
2. Then I declared it in the **typings.d.ts** :
   `declare var kia: any;`
3. And finally I tryed to import it in the file I use **detail.component.ts** : 
   `import * as variable from 'kia';`

I've the error : *error TS2307: Cannot find module 'kia'.*

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: In my **component.ts**, I've changed the import for:
`import * as kia from '../../assets/js/kia.js';`

And I added `"allowJs": true,` in the **tsconfig.json** compilerOptions.

Now I've the error : 
`src/typings.d.ts(3,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'kia' must be of type '{ COMMANDE_INIT: string; COMMANDE_EXECUTER_CALLBACK: string; ACQUITTER_: string; m_NomFenetre: an...', but here has type 'any'.`

Answer (score 0):

You can include it in your index.html as you would normally (inside a script tag) and  if necessary add the type definitions in your typings.d.ts or preferably, find a @types package for it.

Otherwise you can do what you are doing. Just ensure you path is correct and then since you've added it to your typings file you do not need to import it at the top of your ts file, you can just reference it like.

```
const a = kia. ...
```

If you've installed it using an npm package then you should rather import it, as you are doing

Comment: It's a homemade cross application js file, I can't use npm.

I've some trouble understanding how he can find the js file from what little I wrote in **typings.d.ts**.

So I should remove the import and use it directly in my component ?

Comment: @PoncelinJuriaan Have you tried removing the import at the top of your ts file and referenced what you need by just using the kia var you've declared. For example if foo is a function in kia, you can access foo by going kia.foo() anywhere in you project

Comment: If I remove the import in the ts file I don't have any errors anymore, but It doesn't look like it's working.
in the html componant I added : 
`<button onclick="kia.test();">test</button>`

I get in chrome `Uncaught TypeError: kia.test is not a function  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`.

When I browse the sources in chrome I can't find my kia.js, i did find the code in "scripts.bundle.js" though.

Comment: @PoncelinJuriaan You should try it with Angular's built in (click) event handler. So its <button (click)="kia.test();">test</button. Otherwise your function scope will be incorrect and chrome will log the above error

Comment: Thanks we're getting closer =).
But now i've this in the log : 

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (DetailComponent.html:86)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
    at eval (core.js:10587)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)

Comment: Test is an available method though.
If I create a index.html where I import the js in a script balise it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this probleme by removing the import in the component.ts, then add a link method(); in the component.html, and declaring method() { kia.test();} in the componant.ts.