# Image processing in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, image, image-processing

I'm new to AngularJS and I am using angular 6 for web application in that I want to apply some image processing effect on the image like Blur, crop, tagin on the image, Brightness etc.

Is it possible in angular 6?

Can someone guide me which steps need to follow?

Thanks for Help...

Comment: Use [WebGL with `<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Getting_started_with_WebGL)

Comment: Ok, thanks I will read it first then let you know if I have any quires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

The "JavaScript Image Manipulation Program" :-)

[jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)

An image processing library for Node written entirely in JavaScript, with zero external or native dependencies.

Installation: `npm install --save jimp`

Comment: Angular + Jimp is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `canvas` tag to render your images and apply some image processing using the openCV.js library.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html

More over you will have to look for the best practice to include and call javascript files in angular 6. 
[How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j)