# Algolia Places in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, algolia

I would like to integrate the "Placesjs" library of Algolia into an Angular 6 project. However, I do not yet know how to make this type script compliant.

In the example I added this to see what it looks like.

```js
  var placesAutocomplete = places({
    container: document.querySelector('#address-input')
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.9.1"></script>
<input type="search" id="address-input" placeholder="Where are we going?" />
```

Comment: There a guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j/44817445 to deal with adding in JS librarys to Angular, that should help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j)