# How to import / include / load custom JS file in Angula 6

Tags: angular6

Suppose I have custom JS file as below -

1. custom.js
2. test.js
3. papular.js

How we can import / include / load these JS file in Angular6 ?

Thanks & have a good day !!

Comment: Here's an answer for Angular 4 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j), does this work for Angular 6?

Comment: Thanks @JustinWilson, I did it in Angular 4, but don't know ho to do it in Angular 6, and not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the `angular.json` file in your Angular 6 project, and add the js file list to the `"scripts": [],` array.