# How to make angular component aware of your external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular7

In my Angular 7 project, in src folder, I have site.js file where I keep some javascript functions.

This file is referenced in angular.json (under scripts section) and all seems ok. Inside index.html, I see that all functions from site.js are available.

How do I run any of the functions from angular component? It seems that my site.js is ignored by component.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have to import site.js into the component in which you would like to use it:

```
import myFunction from 'site.js';
```

or whatever the appropriate import form for your module would be.

See here: [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j).

You've done everything in the answer except the last step.

Comment: Note: you don't necessarily have to use a type definition