# add and use custom js file in angular 7 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

assuming I have a js file `mylib.js` in an *angular 7* app, located in `assets/mylib.js`:

```
mylib = function(){
    return {
        hi: function() { alert('hi'); }
    };
}();
```

and I want in my `hero-form.component.ts` to be able to call `mylib.hi()`, what would be the proper way to do this ?

I tried to the same as the jquery package that I installed and it works so I added in `angular.json` `-> projects/myproject/architect/build/options/scripts` like this:
`"scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", "src/assets/mylib.js"]`
and in `hero-form.component.ts`:

```
import * as $ from "jquery"; // works, installed via npm
import * as mylib from "mylib"; // cannot find module mylib
```

I test it by calling in the component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    $('body').css('background','gainsboro');
    mylib.hi();    
  }
```

please note, I don't want to add the scripts in the index.html header globally, I want to call import for each component that needs it

Comment: Maybe it will to add it withitn the tsconfig.json into ,
`'include": [
    "./src", // need to be there if you add the include
    "path to the file"
  ]`  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @LukasBonzelett there's no mention of jquery in any of the `tsconfig` files so I assume adding jquery to them won't help either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j)

Comment: @Dblaze47 the question you referenced is about angular 4, and the answer mentions `angular-cli.json` which is not present in angular 7, but it might be useful

Comment: you need to call the local path for `mylib`, unless your lib `mylib` was downloaded from NPM.

Comment: @Omu I missed that sorry. That post contains many of the possible solutions to accomplishing this, and yes it might be useful. :)

Comment: @LostJson, what do you mean by that, which file I need to edit and what to edit it with ?

Comment: Could you create minimal snippet on github?

Comment: @Dblaze47 angular-cli.json is angular.json in Angular 7

Comment: @deathangel908 I've uploaded it here: https://files.fm/u/fgku5mk8

Comment: I found this one https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular

Comment: @LUkasBonzelett yes, using `declare const mylib: any;` as in the link you posted worked, I only had to remove the `export mylib` as was suggested in an answer, you can add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(since the answer that helped me was deleted I'm posting this)

- in the `hero-form.component.ts` I had to do use

`declare const mylib: any;`

instead of `import * as mylib from "mylib"`

- another important thing is that you have close the console (or ctrl+c) running `ng serve` after adding scripts in `angular.json` and run `ng serve` again
- I also had to remove the `export mylib;` from `mylib.js` as suggested in answer, as this was throwing an error `unexpected token export`

I got to this answer by following an article suggested in the comments: https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

Export mylib from mylib.js as (just put it at the bottom of the file):

```
export mylib;
```

Comment: I've added `export mylib;` still getting `Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mylib'`