# Cannot import PapaParse

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble importing PapaParse into my javascript file.

I have downloaded it and tried many different versions of importing it that I have found online

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';
```

and the error I am getting

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Papa from 'papaparse';
                                                                     ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.104 seconds
```

Comment: What framework(s) are you using?

Comment: Angular, would that change things? Im new to this

Comment: How are you setting up Angular to know what 'papaparse' is?  Look at this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j