# External .js file in an Angular 8 project

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to call a function in a .js file from an Angular component, but I get the error "ERROR ReferenceError: myTest is not defined at TechnologiesComponent.onClick".

I have followed the steps described [here](https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular), so I have created a file called custom.js in my src folder. [image: screenshot]

The file contains the following:

```
function myTest() {
  alert('Welcome to custom js');
}

$(function() {
  alert('Hello, custom js');
});
```

I have added the script in the scripts array in my angular.json, like so:

```
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": false,
        "assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": ["src/custom.js"]
      },
```

The .ts file where I want to use the .js file looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare const myTest: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-technologies',
  templateUrl: './technologies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./technologies.component.css']
})
export class TechnologiesComponent {
  onClick() {
    myTest();
  }
}
```

A button is added to my template:
    Click Me

When the button is pressed, the error "ERROR ReferenceError: myTest is not defined at TechnologiesComponent.onClick" is thrown. Why?

Comment: I don't know how this `declare const myTest: any;` will you the reference of `custom.js`? Have you forgot to use `import`? for ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-script-file-in-angular-and-call-a-function-from-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare your function as a variable (in JS both are same)

custom.js

```
myTest = function(){
   alert('Welcome to custom js');
}
```

also, verify if the script is getting imported in the final build

you may need to re-build if you are using **ng serve**

Comment: Declaring functions as variables isn't really an option, since I'm going to import a large, third party library. The custom.js was just to have a MWE. But i was using ng serve, and simply rebuilding solved my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: good that i added that extra line which helped you, we all got stuck in same situation :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use code from .js files in .ts files you should use `export` and `import`.
Example with your project:

custom.js

```
export function myTest() {
  alert('Welcome to custom js');
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as custom from 'src/custom.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  onClick() {
    custom.myTest();
  }
}
```

take note of line `import * as custom from 'src/custom.js';`
It's one of the best ways to import smth from non-ts files.

Structure:

[image: project structure]

Comment: After upgrading to angular 8, scripts suddenly stopped loading in our hybrid app for iOS (worked on web/android). After many days of struggle , I tried this and it works. Strange but it worked . Why did you suggest this, when there are other ways to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using angular 10 and trying to access plane js file and It's not allow to change js file
i.e. can't able to add `export` in it

1. add your js files in `angular.json`

[image]

2. I want to access `print()` function in angular from `myJs.js` and which is like

```js
// MyJS.js

function print(a){
cosole.log(a +" Code from JS");
}
```

3. app.component.ts

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
  
 // following variable name and function name in js file should be same
declare var print: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  onClick() {
   print('Yes');
  }
}
```

4. and fire **ng serve** again

( If still not work for you then try to put your js file in `assets` folder and change the path in `angular.json`)