# Add external file js to an Angular 9 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, slider

I tried to add script.js to angular.json and use it in one component. That's not working. Those who suggest to add script tag to my html file thats not a good idea. Can someone suggest another idea or what I missed to make my script work?

I add my js file called script.js on angular.json

```
 "scripts": [
          "src/assets/js/script.js"
        ]
```

And I declare a variable in slider.ts

```
  declare const owlCarousel: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    owlCarousel();
  }
```

**script.js**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    dots:false,
    nav:true,
    mouseDrag:false,
    autoplay:true,
    animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-script-file-in-angular-and-call-a-function-from-th) address your requirements?

Comment: I already try this method doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

First add function in your script.js

```
export function owlCarousel() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    dots:false,
    nav:true,
    mouseDrag:false,
    autoplay:true,
    animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
    });
}
```

And in your component add this line to import function owlCarousel

```
 import {owlCarousel} from '../../assets/js/script.js' /plz add correct path
```

Notice that slider.ts is not mandatory

Hope useful.

Comment: Why the slider.ts is not mandatory !! I tried to make the script as a function to call it but still doesn't work

Comment: yeah I did &  I tried sample test window.alert('hello!') but js not working I don't know why