# Is there a known way to include Webfow JS animations in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, animation, webflow

We are currently using Angular 8 with Webflow to create our frontend design. Webflow exports the code as HTML and CSS files which are easy to implement. Animations are exported in a Webflow.js file containing lots of unreadable code. The basic question is: **How can we make use of these animations in Angular?**

We tried to implement the animations as an external JS script file following the answers to this question: [How do I include a JavaScript script file in Angular and call a function from that script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-script-file-in-angular-and-call-a-function-from-th)

We would like to use the Webflow animations in Angular 6+. Does anybody know how to use the Webflow.JS file properly?

Comment: if you are asking for code solutions, it is faster to get answers, if you put some code samples of your own, just to show us, what you have done so far.

Comment: We tried multiple approaches but it is difficult to include code because multiple files could be relevant for the solution. We are hoping for someone who has already solved the problem

Comment: alright then. i understand.