# Building a js file with esnext how to use it with angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a js file as shown below UserService.js and source.js which is created using **transformer typescript** my goal is to use this transformed js file in angular.

UserService.js

```
import { Source } from "./source";

 export class UserService {
    
    source = new Source();
    
    demo() {
        this.source.fun();
    }

}
```

Sourcr.js

```
export class Source {
    fun() {
        console.log('hello world');
    }
}
```

When I try to use the file in app.component.ts as shown below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  userService=new UserService();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.demo();
  }
}
```

Below is tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
}
```

I get the following error while doing **ng serve**

```
ERROR in ./dist/out-tsc/UserService.js 4:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export class UserService {
|     
>     source = new Source();
|     
|     demo() {
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-script-file-in-angular-and-call-a-function-from-th

Comment: @Sam I am able to call the function which are outside the class but not able to instantiate the object of that class so i am not able to access the class methods.

Comment: There is likely a problem in your configuration. Are you able to create a small demo repository? I could take a look.

Comment: @Avius here is a sample app [sample-app](https://github.com/aino-shubham/sample-app)

Comment: I understand that `Source.js` is generated somewhere else and it will always be sort of an external JavaScript file. However, it seems that you have full control over `UserService`. Is there any reason why you want it to be a JavaScript file rather than TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Here's **what** is going on here:

1. The builder does not understand the syntax in `UserService.js` (the problematic line is marked with a `>`).
2. This makes the compiler think that the file needs special processing, which is why it suggests using a *loader*.

Here's **why** this happens:

1. You are importing a JavaScript file (`UserService.js`)  into a TypeScript file (`app.component.ts`).
2. This JS file uses syntax from ES2019 (it has a class field).
3. Angular is not instructed to compile JS files - it only compiles TypeScript by default.
4. It attempts to use the file as is and fails because it does not know this JS syntax.

*Disclaimer - this is empirical reasoning, and I can't provide any comprehensive reference. I'm actually not sure why it does not understand that syntax.*

### Solution

I can think of a few ways to solve this problem.

1. Rename `UserService.js` to `UserService.ts`. Angular will then properly transpile the file. Although if in the real setting `Source.js` uses such syntax as well, then it won't be enough.
2. Add `"allowJs": true` to `tsconfig.json > compilerOptions`. This will instruct Angular to treat JS files similar to how it treats TypeScript. This means that all JS files will be transpiled by the compiler.
3. Don't use such modern syntax in your JS files (the code worked fine when I got rid of the class field).

### Note

Since I had a chance to take a look at your repo, I have noticed one issue.

The `scripts` array under `angular.json > projects > sample-app > architect > build > options` is typically used for external libraries, which define their exports at the global level (e.g. jQuery). Since you import `Source.js` directly into `UserService.js`, which you import directly into `app.component.ts`, you shouldn't add these scripts to this array - it really doesn't do anything aside from inflating the size of the bundle.

BTW, if none of the above solutions work for you, it's also possible to use this `scripts` array to solve the problem, but you'd have to change a few more things in the code, which is why I'm not going into details here.