# How to use script in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, script-tag, cornerstone

When I write native HTML file, I can include this script that include `uids object`

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader/master/examples/dicomfile/uids.js"></script>
```

Then I can use this uids referenced from script, like in this line

```
uids[value];
```

but how can I use this script in Angular? I put the script tag in index.html, then when I try to use `uids` in app.component.ts, it doesn't recognize it; saying `Cannot find name 'uids'.ts`

any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-script-file-in-angular-and-call-a-function-from-th

Comment: I'm sorry, it works in case the script file is local only, but in my case it didn't work since it's an online script!

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular

Comment: is your issue that object is not accessible or typescript giving error.
if you have included the script in index.html all you need is to declare the variable so that typescripts compiles e.g. `declare var uuids: any` at the top of .ts file.