# How to insert Java-script file into a angular component.ts Type-script file and execute the onClick function for MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb, express

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as e from 'cors';


declare function click_fun():any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  ngOnInit(): void{
  }

  click_fun(){
  
    alert('Welcome')
  }
}
```

"""How to call in JavaScript file that has all the code for database connection, storing data in MONGODB and credential authentication in click_fun()."""

Comment: Its already answered here, check this out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-script-file-in-angular-and-call-a-function-from-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**- Let us assume our script file `custom.js` looks like this: -**

```
var utilObj = {
    dummyFunc: () => {
        console.log('Calling dummy function!');
    }
}
```

**- Add your javascript/script file in scripts array in `angular.json` file.**

```
"scripts": [
    "src/custom.js" 
 ],
```

Should look like this: -

[image]

**- Add below code snippet in `typings.d.ts`. If this file doesn't exist, create one in `src` folder.**

```
declare var utilObj:any;
```

Keep your variable name similar to property of script file. Here `utilObj` is the property name.

**- Now, You can consume this script/js file directly in your component or .ts file.**

You need not import the file in component file or .ts file now as we have given the typing defination for the script file already in `typings.d.ts` file.

Example: -

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('Starting Application!');
  utilObj.dummyFunc();
}
```

**- Output: -**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!!

I have included my JS file in the scripts folder.

Comment: I have my authentication code in a JS file and instead of writing the whole function in the TS component file, I want to call that file in the form OnClick function. So how do I do that?

Comment: @enzigartiger_coder Please check the updated answer now, have explained it with an example.

Comment: Also, please do not forget to upvote or mark this as an answer if this helps you out.