# Javascript function in Angular "not defined" error

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to get an Angular 17 project to work. I'm using Bootstrap (5), and trying to get the datePicker to work. This requires a bit of JavaScript code, which I am not getting to work. I've followed various tutorials, but somehow I keep on getting a "ReferenceError: datePicker is not defined" error when building the application.

I have taken the following steps:

1. created a file called TestJavaScript.js in my assets folder. This file contains the javascript function as follows

   ```
    $(function(){
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format      :   "YYYY",
        viewMode    :   "years"
        });
     });
   ```
2. Then I added the reference path in the angular.json file in the scripts section as follows:

   ```
        "scripts": [
            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "src/assets/TestJavaScript.js"
        ],
   ```
3. Then, in the component.ts file I declare the function and then try to export it. The "datePicker is not defined" error only occurs in the last step.

   ```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    declare function datePicker(): void;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-available-funds',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [],
      templateUrl: './available-funds.component.html',
      styleUrl: './available-funds.component.css'
    })
    export class AvailableFundsComponent {
      constructor(){
        datePicker();
      }
    }
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: isn't datepicker part of the jqueery UI package, not the base jqueery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a JavaScript script file in Angular and call a function from that script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-script-file-in-angular-and-call-a-function-from-th)

Comment: @JaromandaX; not sure. I've just installed jqueery UI to try it out, but problem persists....

Comment: @yong shun; I've tried this method as well, but also run into issues there :(

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out to be a whole lot easier than I thought.

In Angular, there's no need to manually load JavaScript files. Instead, one can simply include the necessary packages in the Package.json file. After that, we can integrate the package module into the Angular component module, and utilize the selector or directive in the HTML code.

For a practical example, I've been referred to the following link: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples Examples. This should provide some clarity on the process.