# What is declare var in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

in this nodejs code,

```
declare var process: NodeJS.Process;
declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
declare var console: Console; 
declare var __filename: string;
declare var __dirname: string;
```

that...

What's the difference between 'declare var' and 'var'?

When I look up on the googling, I get the word runtime.

wiki says runtime is an operation while a computer program is running....

but i can't understand.

and  line 1, what does it mean by ":" after "process" and then "NodeJS.Process"?

Is that mean "process" is equal "NodeJS.Process"?

also line 4, what does it mean by ":" after "__filename" and then "string"?

Is that mean "__filename" is equal "string"?

thanks you.

Comment: `in this nodejs code` what are you actually looking at? got a link?

Comment: Are you using some kind of preprocessor that does static type checking? That looks more like TypeScript.

Comment: in TypeScript, the part after `:` declares the variables **type**

Comment: to Jaromanda X.   there is https://github.com/IoTKETI/Mobius/// i download this and open VS207. and In the file mobius.js, line 22, there is "global". so i use definition picking then I could see those codes.

Comment: from ONION ... what?

Comment: The snippet is from a [TypeScript declaration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript). See: [DefinitelyTyped's node/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e36116f93c495cc2af65af64217b375a3e39cdbf/types/node/index.d.ts#L90)

Comment: check this thread would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019987/what-does-declare-do-in-export-declare-class-actions

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 13):

When you use:

```
var process: NodeJS.Process;
```

You are creating a variable named `process` (with no value defined) and telling the TypeScript compiler to enforce the `NodeJS.Process` type for assignments.

When you add `declare`:

```
declare var process: NodeJS.Process;
```

You are telling the TypeScript compiler that there is *already* a variable named `process` with the type `NodeJS.Process`. This is useful when you have variables introduced by sources that the compiler is not be aware of.

See [Declaration Files in the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).