# What's the correct way to declare var in node js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, declare

I'm looking at some code in an existing project and came across a js file containing one line:

```
declare var __DEV__: boolean;
```

There is a syntax error that says:

> Expected ; but found var

I tried removing the declare to change the line to:

```
var __DEV__: boolean;
```

which gives the error:

> Expected ; but found :

I've also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745860/what-is-declare-var-in-node-js) to understand how declarations work and confirm that it's necessary for this part of the code. I then compared the code to examples found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables) and couldn't pinpoint the mistake.

I considered changing the variable name, or declaring it differently, but I would like to understand how to do this correctly.

Comment: That's a Typescript construct.  If you're writing vanilla JS, it doesn't apply.

Comment: `declare` is not a javascript keyword.

Comment: @Manaar Consider taking a step back and explain what drove you to ask this particular question.  Jake and I suppose that you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Can you show what `tsconfig.json` looks like? It should exist in the project's root. Also, it would be helpful to show the path of the `.js` file you are having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

That's a Typescript construct. If you're writing vanilla JS, it doesn't apply.

In vanilla JS, just write

`var __DEV__ = true;`
or
`var __DEV__ = false;`

Comment: I don't think removing/modifying the declaration is the correct approach. The user likely needs to understand that the project is not written in javascript, but needs to be transpiled to javascript.

Comment: Agreed. I think that this is a yet another instance of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).