# Declare a const variable in javascript without initialization

Tags: javascript, constants

In javascript, as per my understanding, we can declare variables with let and var keywords and assign it a value later.

```
var a;
a = 5;
```

But, when I try the same approach with const keyword it does not work.

```
const a;
Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
```

I understand my question has a basic contradiction because const keywords are used for storing immutable variables. Therefore, a good coding practice may require it to be initialized while being declared.

However, I want to store global value in a const variable that is being fetched by an API. So, I was wondering if there is a way to assign a value to a pre-declared const variable in javascript?

Comment: What sense does it make? You can't reassign a `const` variable. If you declare it without a value, how would you give it a value later?

Comment: You may be thinking of `declare` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745860/what-is-declare-var-in-node-js

Comment: `const` doesn't mean the value is immutable, it means the variable is immutable.

Comment: I agree with you, it might not be the right practice. However, I was wondering if there is a clever way to store values fetched by api's in vanilla javascript as const global variables.

Comment: @AditeyaPandey No, there's not (without `eval`)

Comment: The proper way to solve this is to store a promise for the response in the global constant.

Comment: @Barmar Sometimes you want to set a `const` inside a block but want it to have a global scope. `const` is block scoped (just like `let`). If we could declare a variable to be const outside a block `const a;` then assign it once inside the block, it would solve the problem. The alternative would be creating a function or refactoring the code. If we could separate scope from the `const` property it would be nice.

Comment: @Rolf That requires you to be able to assign the variable once, not multiple times. But that can't generally be handled with static analysis, it requires runtime checking.

Comment: @Barmar Ideally each characteristic would have separate keyword. For example declare `local a` in the global scope then declare `const a = 123` in the inner loop.  So that the programmer can control scope and constance separately. I would suffer a lot with CSS when a CSS rule would trigger 2 or 3 undesired side effects. Wait this actually sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

`const` applies to the variable, not the value. You have to initialize them, because you can't assign them later -- that's the only difference they have. You can't have a variable that you can assign just once, but not reassign.

If the result is an object, you can declare the constant to hold an empty object, and then use `Object.assign()` to fill it in with the API response.

```
const result = {};
fetch(...).then(response => response.json()).then(data => Object.assign(result, data));
```

Comment: Changed to "fill it in".

Answer (score 3):

Have two ways to create a const with default value, 1 object with properties mutable, 2 array, as you can see bellow.

```
const a = {};
cosnt b = [];
```

Comment: And taking into consideration that array **is** an object ...

Comment: Yes srry for that

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not do that way . In JavaScript const variables must be assigned a value when they are declared:

Incorrect

```
const PI;
PI = 3.14159265359;
```

Correct

```
const PI = 3.14159265359;
```

For more reference you can take a look at this which gives you a better explanation

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so, at least not in run-time. I suggest you consider using TypeScript, which has the `readonly` modifier which will help you protect your variable from being overwritten **during compile-time**.