# TS1183: implementation cannot be declared in ambient context in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Im trying to make a global namespace/function
my code looks like this : abc.ts

```
declare namespace abc {
   export function abc (): xyz {
        console.log('Hello');
        return xyz(200);
    }
}
export = abc
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it ?

Comment: Get rid of `declare`?

Answer (score 5):

Your code will work fine if you remove "declare" keyword

```
namespace abc {
   export function abc (): xyz {
        console.log('Hello');
        return xyz(200);
    }
}
export default abc
```

> declare is used to tell TypeScript that the variable has been created
>   elsewhere. If you use declare, nothing is added to the JavaScript that
>   is generated - it is simply a hint to the compiler.

[What does 'declare' do in 'export declare class Actions'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019987/what-does-declare-do-in-export-declare-class-actions)

---

The implementation can be in the another place in your case. The code below works fine too.

```
declare namespace abc {
   export function abc ();
}

namespace abc {
   function abc (): xyz {
        console.log('Hello');
        return xyz(200);
    }
}

export default abc
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html