# Are global scripts are ignored in Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

It appears that Angular Universal ignores the list of global scripts defined in `angular.json`. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly, or is this a bug worth filing?

---

To reproduce, clone the [`universal-starter`](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) repo.

In `src/app/app.component.ts` add this function declaration:

```
declare function globalFunction(): void;
```

And call it in the constructor:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { globalFunction(); }
}
```

Next, create the file `src/javascripts.js` and add this to it:

```
function globalFunction() {
  console.log("Hello, world!");
}
```

Finally, edit `angular.json` and add the new JavaScript file to the `scripts` array:

```
"scripts": [
  "src/javascripts.js"
]
```

Run `ng serve` and visit `http://localhost:4200`...you should see "Hello, world!" printed to the JavaScript console.

Now build the Universal app using `npm run build:prerender`...you should see the error: `ReferenceError: globalFunction is not defined`.

Comment: See GitHub [bug report](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1114).

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same issues here

Comment: No solution, just had to refactor code to not depend on `scripts`

Answer (score -1):

why are you using `declare function globalFunction(): void;` ?

when you use declare statement, angular assumes that `globalFunction` is defined elsewhere. If you use declare, nothing is added to the JavaScript that is generated - it is simply a hint to the compiler.

Remove the declare statement and you will see taht your function will work

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020317/1118978)

Comment: I do not believe this is correct: the declare simply hints to TypeScript that the function *should* exist at runtime and it has the correct types for it. If I remove the declaration, I get a compile-time error.

Comment: In your reference: "For example, if you use an external script..." This external script *was* defined in my `angular.json` file and the function is defined in `src/javascripts.js`

Comment: but did you import it globally in your app-root? you need to import it to be able to use it. declare does not import. It is just a hint for compiler. so that compiler does not give error

Comment: Yes, the external script file is imported in `angular.json`