# pass generic arguments to a React.FunctionComponent in typescript declaration file

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add a type definition to a `.d.ts` file for  a `React.FunctionComponent` that looks like this:

```
Tree.propTypes = {
  root: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.func,
  top: PropTypes.number,
  left: PropTypes.number,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
  nodeSize: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
  separation: PropTypes.func,
  linkComponent: PropTypes.any,
  nodeComponent: PropTypes.any
};

export default function Tree({
  top,
  left,
  className,
  root,
  size,
  nodeSize,
  separation,
  children,
  linkComponent = DefaultLink,
  nodeComponent = DefaultNode,
  ...restProps
}) {
```

import React from 'react';
import { TreeLayout, HierarchyPointNode, HierarchyNode } from 'd3-hierarchy';

I have come up with this approach:

```
export interface TreeProps<Datum, LinkComponentType = any, NodeComponentType = any> {
  root: HierarchyNode<Datum>;
  top?: number;
  left?: number;
  className?: string;
  size?: [number, number];
  linkComponent: React.ComponentType<LinkComponentType>;
  separation: (a: HierarchyPointNode<Datum>, b: HierarchyPointNode<Datum>) => number;
  nodeComponent: React.ComponentType<NodeComponentType>;
  nodeSize?: [number, number];
}


export declare function Tree<
  Datum,
  LinkComponentType = any,
  NodeComponentType = any
>(args: TreeProps<Datum, LinkComponentType, NodeComponentType>): JSX.Element;
```

Is this the correct way of typing this, I think it should be a React.FunctionComponent like:

```
export declare const Tree<Datum>
```

But then I would not be able to pass in the type arguments.

Comment: Why do you use the declare keyword here?

Comment: do `linkComponent` and `nodeComponent` impact the props available to the component ? It would seem like they would. Otherwise `export declare function` seems ok, if you want to use a `const` it should be `export declare const Tree: <
  Datum,
  LinkComponentType = any,
  NodeComponentType = any
>(args: TreeProps<Datum, LinkComponentType, NodeComponentType>) => JSX.Element;` But I see no need to do this, they should work the same in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a module in `.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'NAME_OF_THE_PACKAGE' {
    export interface TreeProps<Datum, LinkComponentType = any, NodeComponentType = any> {
        root: HierarchyNode<Datum>;
        top?: number;
        left?: number;
        className?: string;
        size?: [number, number];
        linkComponent: React.ComponentType<LinkComponentType>;
        separation: (a: HierarchyPointNode<Datum>, b: HierarchyPointNode<Datum>) => number;
        nodeComponent: React.ComponentType<NodeComponentType>;
        nodeSize?: [number, number];
    }

    export function Tree<Datum, LinkComponentType = any, NodeComponentType = any>(
        args: TreeProps<Datum, LinkComponentType, NodeComponentType>
    ): JSX.Element;
}
```

Where `NAME_OF_THE_PACKAGE` is exactly the name you import the package or install it via npm or yarn.

This way, you will be able to import `TreeProps` and `Tree` this way

```
import { TreeProps, Tree } from 'NAME_OF_THE_PACKAGE'
```

You can read more about modules [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) (check the example of how JavaScript libs are declared - "Working with Other JavaScript Libraries").

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a type like this

```
export type Tree<D, LC = any, NC = any> =
    React.FunctionComponent<TreeProps<D, LC, NC>> => JSX.Element
```

Usage

```
const Tree: Tree<a,b,c> = (props) => <></>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
declare const Tree: React.FunctionComponent<TreeProps<Datum, LinkComponentType, NodeComponentType>>;

export default Tree;
```

`Tree` will be of type `React.FunctionComponent<P>` which is `(props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;` (function component).

May be you've been confused by `declare` keyword. The best description I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019987/what-does-declare-do-in-export-declare-class-actions).

To create function of type `React.FunctionComponent<P>` use syntax

```
const Tree: React.FunctionComponent<TreeProps<Datum, LinkComponentType, NodeComponentType>> =
(props) => {
    return <div className={props.className}>
        Some div
        </div>
}
```

Note that here is no need for `declare` keyword.

Comment: i am creating a declaration file for a 3rd party so there is s need

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you comment. You mean 'so there is I need' or 'so there is no need'?

Comment: i’m writing a declaration file index.d.ts for a 3rd party library that does not have a declaration file.  are you still saying i dint need declare

Comment: To declare types for third party lib you should use `declare` keyword. First code snippet should suit your needs. Code snippet without `decalre` is to difference between declaring and implementing Function component