# Typescript to Javascript export

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a sample typescript objects as

```
declare const S3 = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/icons";
declare const SVG = "svg-file-icons";

declare interface MyIcons {
  "image/jpeg": string;
  "image/jpg": string;
}

export const FILE_ICONS_SVG: MyIcons = {
  "image/jpeg": `${S3}/${SVG}/jpg.svg`,
  "image/jpg": `${S3}/${SVG}/jpg.svg`
};
```

I am declaring this object in a share NPM Package to maintain consistency in all my projects. But TSC compilation gives me something like this.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.FILE_ICONS_SVG = {
    "image/jpeg": `${S3}/${SVG}/jpg.svg`,
    "image/jpg": `${S3}/${SVG}/jpg.svg`
};
```

As it is evident that **S3** and **SVG** are not defined in the compiled js file  and thus gives errors on usage.

> **How can this be fixed??**

Comment: What does `declare const` do?

Comment: @VLAZ, declares a value that can not be changed.

Comment: `const` does that, but what does the `declare` keyword do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'declare' do in 'export declare class Actions'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019987/what-does-declare-do-in-export-declare-class-actions)

Comment: declare const is a typescript way to initialize a constant.

Comment: There you go - apparently, that's what `declare` does.

Comment: No, it isn't - see the dupe. It has different semantics.

Comment: @VLAZ you are right. I resolved my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `declare` does not really "declare" something.

`declare` is only used to tell the **type-system** that something with the declared name and type exists.

If you want to define a constant that should exist **outside of the type-system**, aka exist at runtime, you have to remove the declare keyword.

> `declare`'d things do not have any impact on the runtime

#### Why does `declare` exist?

If you think about how the web works, you have a html file. In that html you can include scripts. Those scripts may be completely independent from one another, but also use stuff from other scripts.

So if you have one file that attaches something to the `window` for example in one file, and have another file that then uses this object, the typescript type-system has no way of knowing that that object exists, so you can tell the type-system of its existence by using `declare`

---

So it should be

```
const S3 = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/icons";
const SVG = "svg-file-icons";
```