# How to connect telegram web app to angular

Tags: angular, telegram

I don't know how to connect telegram to angular. In the HTML file I do this -

```
<script src="./assets/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
```

But I don’t know what to do in the component to call the function I need.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-mini-apps

I searched for a solution on this site but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

First, add it to your **angular.json** file:

```
"scripts": [
    "./assets/telegram-web-app.js"
]
```

Then in your component, declare a var with the same name as a telegram JS export. This tells angular what to look for in the JS ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020317/21521159)):

```
declare var telegramJSObjName:any;
```

And use it in your component like:

```
declare var telegramJSObjName:any;

constructor(){}

callFunction1() {
    telegramJSObjName.func1();
}
```

If you have issues, try

1. adding `"allowJs": true` within `"compilerOptions"` in tsconfig.json
2. creating the file src/**typings.d.ts** and moving all 'declare' statements in here.

See these posts for more on how to access functions from a javascript file:
[Including JS in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817445/21521159)  (recommended approach)
[Including with a <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56237766/21521159)